# How to move image thumbnails into custom folder for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, images, thumbnails

I have adapted Philipp's answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125784/each-custom-image-size-in-custom-upload-directory) to move all thumbnails to a custom folder. How do we make this work for a particular custom post type?

```
function custom_rename_images($image) {
        // Split the $image path
        $info = pathinfo($image);
        $dir = $info['dirname'] . '/';
        $ext = '.' . $info['extension'];
        $name = wp_basename($image, '$ext');

        if(!is_dir($dir.'_thumbs')){
            mkdir($dir.'_thumbs');
        }

        // New Name
        $new_name = substr_replace($image,'/_thumbs/',strrpos($image,'/'),1);

        // Rename the intermediate size
        $did_it = rename($image, $new_name);

        // Return if successful
        if ($did_it) return $new_name;

        // Return on fail
        return $image;
    //}
}
add_filter('image_make_intermediate_size', 'custom_rename_images');
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bellow filter in the `functions.php`

```
<?php
add_filter( 'upload_dir', function($args) {
    if( !isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ) {
        return $args;
    }

    $post_type_name = get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] );

    if( $post_type_name = 'custom_post_type' ) {
        // Set the new path depends on current post_type
        $newdir = '/' . $post_type_name;
        $args['path']    = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['path'] ); //remove default subdir
        $args['url']     = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['url'] );
        $args['subdir']  = $newdir;
        $args['path']   .= $newdir;
        $args['url']    .= $newdir;
        return $args;
    }

    return $args;
} ); ?>
```

https://gist.github.com/mostafasoufi/c525572d9b4404808b0a7bbf14f09ffa