# Store thumbnails and uploads in different directories?

Tags: thumbnails

I've followed the accepted answer in [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/125784/94498) question to generate my thumbnails in a custom way.

I extended the image editor class as:

```
class WP_Image_Editor_Custom extends WP_Image_Editor_GD {
    public function generate_filename($prefix = NULL, $dest_path = NULL, $extension = NULL) {
        // If empty, generate a prefix with the parent method get_suffix().
        if(!$prefix)
            $prefix = $this->get_suffix();

        // Determine extension and directory based on file path.
        $info = pathinfo($this->file);
        $dir  = $info['dirname'];
        $ext  = $info['extension'];

        // Determine image name.
        $name = wp_basename($this->file, ".$ext");

        // Allow extension to be changed via method argument.
        $new_ext = strtolower($extension ? $extension : $ext);

        // Default to $_dest_path if method argument is not set or invalid.
        if(!is_null($dest_path) && $_dest_path = realpath($dest_path))
            $dir = $_dest_path;

        // Return our new prefixed filename.
        return trailingslashit($dir)."{$prefix}/{$name}.{$new_ext}";
    }
function multi_resize($sizes) {
    $sizes = parent::multi_resize($sizes);
    //This will generate proper metadata for thumbnails
    foreach($sizes as $slug => $data)
        $sizes[$slug]['file'] = $slug."/".$data['file'];

    return $sizes;
}
}
```

Now, original uploads will be stored in `uploads` and the thumbnails will be stored in `uploads/thumbnail/`, `/uploads/medium/` and `uploads/large/`.

What i want is one of these 2 scenarios:

**1-** to store original uploads in a subfolder such as `uploads/original` and the thumbnails in `uploads/thumbnail/`, `/uploads/medium/` and `uploads/large/`.

**2-** to store the original images in `uploads/` and the thumbnails in a folder named `thumbs/`, OUTSIDE the upload directory, in the root.

I was able to achieve number 2, However, when i call a function such as `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` it will append my custom thumbnail link (stored in post metadata) to the upload directory, producing a link like:

`http://example.com/uploads/thumbs/medium/image.jpg`

The correct format must be like:

`http://example.com/thumbs/medium/image.jpg`

Is it possible to overwrite the metadata while being called to point to the proper file??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the thumbnail URLs are generated relatively to the upload folder. So trying to store them outside the uploads folder is not going to be a good idea.

There are hacks to filter the output for functions such as `the_post_thumbnail_url()`, but considering side issues such as the thumbnails not being able to be deleted, it's not worth a try.

What i was able to achieve, is to store the generated thumbnails in a different subdirectory, inside the uploads folder, and then protect the original uploads folder by setting the proper rules in the `.htaccess` file, in case you want to protect them from the visitor, making them forbidden to be accessed directly.

I was able to make a copy of the original generator class in `wp-image-editor-gd.php` to store the thumbnails in subdirectory. Here is how to do so:

First, we set our own class as the primary image generator:

```
add_filter('wp_image_editors', 'custom_wp_image_editors');
function custom_wp_image_editors($editors) {
    array_unshift($editors, "custom_WP_Image_Editor");
    return $editors;
}
```

We then include the necessary classes to be extended:

```
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . "/class-wp-image-editor.php";
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . "/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php";
```

And finally setting the path:

```
class custom_WP_Image_Editor extends WP_Image_Editor_GD {
    public function generate_filename($suffix = null, $dest_path = null, $extension = null) {
        // $suffix will be appended to the destination filename, just before the extension
        if (!$suffix) {
            $suffix = $this->get_suffix();
        }
        $dir = pathinfo($this->file, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
        $ext = pathinfo($this->file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $name = wp_basename($this->file, ".$ext");
        $new_ext = strtolower($extension ? $extension : $ext );
        if (!is_null($dest_path) && $_dest_path = realpath($dest_path)) {
            $dir = $_dest_path;
        }
        //we get the dimensions using explode
        $size_from_suffix = explode("x", $suffix);
        return trailingslashit( $dir ) . "{$size_from_suffix[0]}/{$name}.{$new_ext}";
    }
}
```

Now the thumbnails will be stored in different sub-folders, based on their width. For example:

```
/wp-content/uploads/150/example.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/600/example.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/1024/example.jpg
```

And so on.

### Possible issue

Now there might be an issue when we upload images smaller than the smallest thumbnail size. For example if we upload an image, sized `100x100`pixels while the smallest thumbnail size is `150x150`, another folder will be created in the uploads directory. This might result in a lot of subdirectories in the uploads directory. I have solved this issue with another approach, in [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/266968/94498) question.

Answer (score 1):

> 2- to store the original images in uploads/ and the thumbnails in a folder named thumbs/, OUTSIDE the upload directory, in the root.

Following your second scenario since you're already halfway through it.
You can use the following :

```
        add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', function ( $image, $attachment_id, $size ) {

        // Make sure $image is not false.
        if ( $image ) {
            switch ( $size ) {
                // Add your custom sizes as cases here.
                case 'thumbnail':
                case 'medium':
                case 'large':
                case 'mysize':
                    /*
                     * This will simply convert the link from
                    http://example.com/uploads/thumbs/medium/image.jpg
                    to
                    http://example.com/thumbs/medium/image.jpg
                    only for thumbnails not for original images.
                    */
                    $image[0] = str_replace( '/uploads/', '/', $image[0] );
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return $image;
    }, 10, 3 );
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you. Does this code apply while calling the function or while saving the thumbnails? because i added it to my `functions.php` and nothing changed.

Comment: This code will change the image source URL whenever the wp_get_attachment_image_src() function is used to get the image thumbnails.

Comment: My bad, the array index was incorrect it should be $image[0] instead if $image['src']

Comment: Your most welcome! :)

Comment: Is the answer for other question not working? Please close this question and continue to the other question to prevent unnecessary comments here.