# Is there a hook which fires after all thumbnails are generated?

Tags: images, uploads, hooks, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I want to upload the image and all generated thumbnails to another server (as backup). I only found [add_attachment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_attachment/), but this is fired right after the image was uploaded and the postmeta table was updated.

I want to wait until all thumbnail sizes are generated and then take the files and upload them to the other server. Is there any hook which matches my expectations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thumbnails in WordPress *can* be generated by using [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/), this function fires a filter after generating all the thumbnails [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/) and the filter provides `$metadata` and `$attachment_id` to the hooked functions.

You can hook your custom function to this filter.

`$metadata` : Attachment metadata. 
What you need is `$metadata['sizes']['<size-name>']`, the `<size-name>` is the name of thumbnail size added by `add_image_size()` or the default ones.
e.g.

```
$metadata[sizes] => Array
       (
           [thumbnail] => Array
               (
                   [file] => example_image-150x150.jpg
                   [width] => 150
                   [height] => 150
                   [mime-type] => image/jpeg
               )
           [medium] => Array
               (
                   [file] => example_image-4-300x194.jpg
                   [width] => 300
                   [height] => 194
                   [mime-type] => image/jpeg
               )
           [mysize] => Array
               (
                   [file] => example_image-4-400x400.jpg
                   [width] => 400
                   [height] => 400
                   [mime-type] => image/jpeg
               )
       )
```

from here you can know which sizes exist for the certain attachment, and only upload those sizes/thumbnails.

To get those thumbnails use a function like `wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, $size_name)` to retrieve the thumbnail urls.

**(Optional)** : Install the **Force Regenerate Thumbnails** plugin to rerun the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` for previously uploaded images too.

Comment: Hi, can you please take a look into these questions too? it's been a long time but no one seems to know how to help ... [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/255317/94498) and [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/255462/94498). thanks.

Comment: @JackJohansson Sure thing.