# Is it possible to split Default WP Media directory to multiple Folder/Subdomain?

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

Is it possible to split Default WP Media directory to multiple Folder/Subdomain? Coz, WP auto-generated images make sure responsive. So, I want to split media directory to separate fo Example: Featured Image Directory, Main Image, 300x300 Crop etc

I tried below code on wp-config.php, but it works for a single directory, not multiple :(

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'example' );
```

Comment: I'm not sure why would you want this, the internal structure of the `wp-content/uploads` folder shouldn't be relevant and has no bearing on the browser or SEO. Code should handle attachment IDs, not attachment file URLs. Can you provide some context?

Comment: When I upload an image to my post, it's automatically generated 3 different dimensions. I'm trying to change each generated images from the different directory. Example: postimage.jpg, postimage-300x300.jpg, post-image-150x150.jpg. Now, I want to separate 300x300, 150x150 from separate media directory.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but I don't know why you're trying to do it. What's the reason behind doing this? I don't see the benefit or the problem it solves

Comment: I just checked my Media folders. Currently, It contains 140K+ images file :(

Comment: that's a lot of files but I don't see what that has to do with moving files into other folders. I take it you don't have the organise into subfolders by date checkbox checked? You should never need to go into that folder, it's managed by WP. Please explain the original problem that your question is trying to solve rather than the solution you've come up with to solve it

Comment: It would take a long time (many seconds) and place heavy load on the server to get a directory listing via FTP of 140,000 files. Depending on the file system, its best to keep to less than about 20,000 files in one folder and preferably fewer than 5,000 files in a folder.

Comment: It is never to late for an [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125784/each-custom-image-size-in-custom-upload-directory/126369#126369). :-)